What should we do with "How to estimate your score for an HSK practice exam?"?
The question is here: How to estimate your score for an HSK practice exam?.
It was asked in 2013, and the top/accepted answer is now obsolete (as per my understanding).  If I recall correctly, this kind of "scaling" (based on other students' marks) was original applied to the new HSK, but it was subsequently replaced by a 60% "pass" threshold, with the addition of listing your marks in each section as a percentage, which is the current system.
Leaving this question "as is" might be confusing for those who want to estimate their HSK score.  However, I'm not quite sure what the correct course of action here is.
Question: What should we do with this question?

I think a simple update, stating what has changed  is enough
